# double click on mvc 4 web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am preparing a mvc 4 application and I am pretty new to it. I would like to implement a functionality like by double clicking a row of mvc 4 webgrid I should call an action method in ajax. But unfortunately I could not find how to implement double click on mvc 4 web grid.
Can you please help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event in jQuery. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('table td').dblclick(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    // do something with the result from your AJAX call
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously there are lots of improvements that could be done to this code. For example you could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes on your grid to specify the url to the controller action that needs to be invoked and then externalize this script in a separate javascript file. You might also need to adjust the jQuery selector to match your WebGrid element.

Comment: Thanks for your help Darin. But I am not sure why posting is happening twice. I did put my grid inside a div and used $('#hiddendiv').dblclick. And I would also like to retrieve the row content value say Id field value after double clicking.

Comment: Depending on where is this id field located on your table you could retrieve it inside the `.dblclick` event. For example you could get the containing `tr` and then descend to find the corresponding `td` containing the id: `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.someClassThatYouCouldApplyToTheTdContainingYourId').html();`.